# How to simulate SHIFT+HOME in windows using JAVA Robot

Tags: java, swing

I am using JAVA Robot to simulate keyboard's SHIFT+HOME operation, code is simple:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

After test, it can simulate shift and home, but no combined effort.
How to correct it?

Comment: Using java 1.8, windows 7

Comment: Don't add comments, just edit question with more information

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)
they say that VK that refer to multiple keys can result in different behavior because it cannot be determined which one was referred, maybe thats for you. BTW: have you tried if your PC supports that operation outside of your Java program?

Answer (score 1):

I pretty sure, there's no other way to do this.

Comment: to less reputation to comment @ItFreak

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all above, resolved.
Add "Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK, false);" before the actions